# Nextflow+Conda: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: conda, nextflow

I am using `Nextflow` to create a module, in which I use conda to build the environment for the tool. I specified the `.yml` file to create the conda environment and when running `nextflow` (I run on 2 different machines) this error occurs:

```
Failed to create Conda environment
  command: conda env create --prefix /user/hphuc/environment/Phuc_conda/bowtie2_align-f4ac932f9c1e20c19d9aaa18cf6f0df2 --file /home/phucnguyen/.nextflow/assets/Phuc/env/conda-bowtie2.yml
  status : 1
  message:
    ==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
      current version: 4.12.0
      latest version: 24.1.2
    
    Please update conda by running
    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
    
    
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/phucnguyen/.conda/pkgs/perl-5.32.1-7_hd590300_perl5.conda'
```

I tried running the error command, separately and `conda` ran continuously without stopping

```
conda env create --prefix /user/hphuc/environment/Phuc_conda/bowtie2_align-f4ac932f9c1e20c19d9aaa18cf6f0df2 --file /home/phucnguyen/.nextflow/assets/Phuc/env/conda-bowtie2.yml
```

Comment: Show the YAML. Are the channels declared correctly? Sometimes channels get added by context. Otherwise, it's complaining about the package cache - perhaps the "user" executing the NextFlow process does not have the correct permissions.

Comment: I also have a suspicion that you might be getting an error because you are using a version of conda that is 20 major releases out of date. Start with updating conda, and if the error persists, then please provide the `yml` file as suggested by @merv

Comment: "*...20 major releases out of date.*" - that's not entirely accurate. Conda switched from semantic to chronological versioning with `4.14` succeeded by `22.9` (Sept. 2022). The v4.12 release is just under 2 years old and Conda interfaces (YAML spec, repodata schema, package architecture, internal environment metadata) have remained stable during that time.